# get the ingredients of a recipe in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table menu which consists of (recipe_id,ingredient_id,category_id),ingredient w/c consist of(ingredient_id,name),category(category_id,name) and category_ingredient w/c consist of (ingredient_id,category_id). I want to get all the ingredients of a recipe but my code won't work. Please help me.

VIEW:

```
   <form method="post">

 <table class="table-responsive table table-hover">
    <tr>        
        <td><strong>Recipe Ingredients</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($products as $product){
        $product_id = $product['recipe_id'];
    ?>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <?php foreach($this->products_model->getRecipeIngridients($product['recipe_id']) as $ing): ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-10"><li name="ingredients[]" value="<?php echo $ing->ingredient_id ?>" <?php echo (in_array($ing->ingredient_id)) ?>><?php echo $ing->name ?></li></div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>


        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

MODEL:

```
function getIngredientsInCategory($category_id)
{
    $this->db->select('ingredient_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('category_ingredient');

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $ingredient[] = $row->ingredient_id;
    }

    $this->db->where_in('ingredient_id', $ingredient);
    $query = $this->db->get('ingredient');
    return $query->result();

}

function getRecipeIngridients($recipe_id)
{

    $this->db->where('recipe_id', $recipe_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('menu');
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $ingredient_id[] = $row->ingredient_id;
    }

    return $ingredient_id;
}
```

Comment: duplicate question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getRecipeIngridients()` function you are only return `ingredient_id` not `name`.

And second issue it that, you are printing `ingredient_id` as object which is an array in your model function `$ingredient_id[] = $row->ingredient_id;`

**Modified Function:**

```
function getRecipeIngridients($recipe_id)
{
    $this->db->where('recipe_id', $recipe_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('menu');
    $result = $query->result(); // return all data in object form.
    return $result;
}
```

**Code Inside the foreach loop:**

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<li name="ingredients[]" value="<?php echo $ing->ingredient_id ?>">
    <?php echo $this->db->get_where("ingredient",array("ingredient_id"=>$ing->ingredient_id))->row()->name; ?>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: it says undefined property name :(

Comment: only  ingredient_id.

Comment: all name of the ingredients are in the ingredient table

Comment: it means, $ing->name is undefined here right @MSE ingredient_id is fine

Comment: @devpro  Check now i have edited your answer... <?php echo $ing->name; ?> to <?php echo $this->db->get_where("ingredient",array("ingredient_id"=>$ing->ingredient_id))->row()->name; ?> :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar: well, this is good, i am looking for inner join in model.. :) thumbs up.. sound good. any way where is abdulla

Comment: @MSE: glad to know, happy coding friend.

Comment: In my opinion ** group_concat(`ingredient_id`) as ingredients** and **group_concat(`category_id`) as categories** from **menu**  willl be good. as there can be more ingredients and categories present for single racipe.